# Ubuntu unable to see the main Windows drive from live media

Tags: partitioning, live-usb

I am trying to install Ubuntu on a machine with a single internal hard drive with Windows on it, previously encrypted with BitLocker.

For some reason during manual partitioning in the installation *as well as* in the live version of the system it can not see the main Windows drive that I would like to override (whether with fdisk, lsblk, gparted etc). It recognizes the USB partition only as /dev/sda1. There is **no other drives, no unallocated volume**.

I've logged into windows and decrypted the drive, also disabled safe boot, but nothing has changed. I've tried all of the above from the live GParted USB and PuppyLinux but no luck.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think so. Cannot use manual partitioning during installation because the LiveUSB cannot see the drive *at all*.

Comment: How is your BIOS configured for your hard drive?  Is it set to AHCI?  I had to set mine to that for my Linux to see it properly.  However, if it is not set to AHCI you will have to setup something in Windows so that you don't have to reinstall it after you configure to AHCI.  Off the top of my head I cannot remember what application I had to setup on Windows before I changed to AHCI.

Comment: @Terrance, that's it! It was set to RAID 0 for some reason, after changing it to AHCI Ubuntu immediately recognized it. Does that have any implications on the fact that I have NVME drive?

Thanks so much!

Comment: It shouldn't have any implications that I am aware of.  The only thing that I was concerned about is that when you change to AHCI Windows may not boot.  That's about it.  And you're very welcome!

Comment: @Terrance thank you! just checked and Windows happens to boot just fine after changing to AHCI too! thanks!!!